# Can’t boot to Windows, stuck on Grub BASH-like command line

Tags: boot, bash, grub, boot-camp

I have installed Grub in Windows through bootcamp on a MacBook, to dual boot ChromeOS and windows .
However after repairing the hard disk in MacOS disk utility grub shows the command prompt interface and refuses get into the GRUB boot menu

It shows

```
minimal BASH-like editing is supported.for the first word, TAB lists
possible commands completions.anywhere else TAB lists the possible device or file completion.
```

When I type exit I get

```
grub> error exit command not found
```

Pressing Esc only starts a new line, while choosing Windows from MacOS Startup manager will freeze the screen.

This might be useful

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

How can I boot in to my Windows partition from this stage?

Comment: `installed Grub in Windows` .. not to be a stickler.. but no, you didn't.  It will be easier for you to understand what went wrong if you keep that in mind.  GRUB is one thing.. a bootloader.. Windows is another.. an operating system (which actually has it's own bootloader).. boot camp is YET ANOTHER bootloader :^P  Honestly, I am impressed that you are even close to pulling this off :)  GOOD LUCK!

Comment: The actual amount of damage done may depend on whether your Mac's bootcamp is in an MBR wrapper or an EFI bootloader - but one thing's for sure… trying to install Grub from inside Windows running in Boot Camp was really not the way to go. You'd probably do best to just trash it all & recover from backup. Then do this from the Mac side. There are a myriad guides on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you are in the GRUB console from there you need to use `ls` on those **hdxx** and find out your windows installation.

after that you should do the following, assuming that (hd0,gpt1) is the partition that you've identified has having the windows install

```
insmod chain
insmod ntfs
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
chainloader +1
```

Comment: We don't yet know where Windows put Grub. If it was inside an MBR wrapper it will have been pretty random & fairly damaging.

Comment: @Tetsujin On UEFI systems -- which should cover any Intel-era Macs -- GRUB should be installed in the EFI system partition and as an UEFI boot option. The first logical block (historically named MBR) is generally ignored.

Comment: @mcendu - Macs don't have UEFI, but it depends on how old the Mac was; the OP never said. Older Boot Camp installs used a protective MBR system, effectively hiding the true disk format from Windows. Trying to install grub [or do anything to the drive structure itself] from Windows would result in some really unpredictable results & usually a bricked install, because Windows thinks it's in charge of the whole drive - but it isn't. It also has no clue what HFS is.